# ListView is not notifying

Tags: android, listview, notify

I am using a list fragment to in a customized navigation drawer. I want to change the color of a text view in the list item while pressing. I am passing item click position to adapter and notify the adapter. But it is not working. but when i set the adapter again it is working. But the movement is not smooth . What should i do to overcome this issue?

Following is the ListItem click of fragment,

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView lView, View v, final int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(lView, v, position, id);
    adapter.setSelectedIndex(position);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

and the adapter having the following code,

```
public void setSelectedIndex(int ind)
{

    selectedIndex = ind;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

my onactivity created

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    menuitemlist=new ArrayList<MenuItem>();
    menuitemlist.clear();
    for(int i=0;i<menulist.length;i++){
        MenuItem item=new MenuItem();
        item.icon=iconlist[i];
        item.menuText=menulist[i];
        item.status=0;
        menuitemlist.add(item);
    }

    adapter=SlidingListAdapter.newInstance(myActivity, menuitemlist);       
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Comment: why are you setting adapter inside onListItemClick?

Comment: Because ,adapter is not notifying .I want to change the color of a textview that is present in list item. When i just called adapter notification change is not happening. While setting adapter textview color is changing

Comment: Please show the if condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1

```
Set your list adapter outside `onListItemClick()`

    lView.setAdapter(adapter);

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView lView, View v, final int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(lView, v, position, id);
        adapter.setSelectedIndex(position);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Method 2

```
View lastSelectedView = null;

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView lView, View v, final int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(lView, v, position, id);
    if(lastSelectedView != null){
      TextView txtView = (TextView)lastSelectedView.findViewById(R.id.x);
      txtView.setTextColor(defaultColor);
    }
    TextView txtView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.x);
    txtView.setTextColor(pressedColor);

    lastSelectedView = v;
}
```

Method 3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ff0000"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#00ff00"/>
    <item android:color="#000000"/>

</selector>
```

and set this selector file  as textColor for TextView

Comment: Actually i am setting adapter inside on activity created.since it is not notifying the adapter i am calling adapter again.

Comment: I tried the method 2 it is working fine in first time press. Then it is not working. what should i change ?